# Pasar datos a trave de un enlace

Tags: jquery, ajax

A través de un foreach:

```
foreach ($conexion->query($cefpp) as $row) {    
        $id = $row['id'];
        $dato = $row['dato'];
        echo "<a href='plantilla.php?id=".$id."' class="dato" id="dato"  data-valor='".$dato."'>";
}
```

Muestro varios enlaces y paso un valor que varia según el enlace.

Quiero que a través de ajax y usando jquery ese dato se muestre en otra parte de la página donde tengo un div, que es donde se debe cargar:

```
<div id="dato" class="dato"></div>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").on("click", "a", function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: $(this).attr("href").valueOf()                     
            })                                                                                            
            .done(function(data) {

                if (data) {
                    if ($(this).attr("id").valueOf() == "dato") {
                        var dato = $(this).attr("data-valor").valueOf();
                        $(".dato").html(dato);
                    }   
                else {
                    alert("Data no tiene valor");
                }           
            })
            .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                if(jqXHR.status === 0) {
                alert('Not connect: Verify Network.');

              } else if(jqXHR.status == 404) {

                alert('Requested page not found [404]');

              } else if(jqXHR.status == 500) {

                alert('Internal Server Error [500].');          

              } else if(textStatus === 'parsererror') {

                alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');

              } else if(textStatus === 'timeout') {

                alert('Time out error.');

              } else if(textStatus === 'abort') {

                alert('Ajax request aborted.');

              } else {

                alert('Uncaught Error: ' + jqXHR.responseText);         
              }
          })
          .always(function(result) {
          });
    });
});
```

El error que me devuelve la consola de Firefox es:

> TypeError: $(...).attr(...) is undefined

```
var dato = $(this).attr("data-valor").valueOf();
```

Si en vez **this** pongo -->

```
var enlace= "." + $(this,"a").prop("class");
var dato = $(enlace).attr("data-valor").valueOf();
```

Aparentemente funciona, pero en realidad muestra el primer resultado del foreach.

¿Porque pasa esto? ¿Que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: `echo "<a href='plantilla.php?id=".$id."' data-valor='".$dato."'>";` en estos enlaces no hay ningun atributo id. entonces `$(this).attr("id").valueOf() == "dato"` esta comprovación no te funcionará. Te lo encontrará si utilizas `echo "<a href='plantilla.php?id=".$id."' id='dato' data-valor='".$dato."'>";`

Comment: @TxemaAlment aunque `id` tiene que ser unico.

Comment: Tienes razón, entonces podria utilizar el `$id` que le da php o si utiliza `class="dato"`, comprovarlo como  `if($(this).hasClass('dato'))'

Comment: php no esta asignando ninguna id al enlace, es una key mas de la url, debe descomponer la url para poder saber el valor de esta y así hacer su análisis

Comment: Es verdad, aquí me olvide de poner:  `class="dato" id="dato"` pero en el código si que lo tengo puesto y el resultado es el que os indico.

Comment: Ya he corregido el enunciado. ¿Me recomendáis que pase el Id de PHP como valor de referencia al class?

Comment: Pero entonces luego en el if ¿como hago la sentencia? `if ($(this).attr("id").valueOf() == "dato") {` Porque si se lo indico se que dato espera, pero si se lo genera, no se como lo comprara.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final lo solucione de la siguiente manera:

Primero había que inicializar la variable dato vacía, y que comprobar que esta vacía para asignarle el valor de data-valor.

Una vez hecho esto y dentro de la función data comprobamos que el valor de dato sea igual al id (Creo que con class funcionaría igual, no lo he probado) y si lo es, enviamos el html al selector dato. Pongo el código a continuación:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").on("click", "a", function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();


            $.ajax({
                url: $(this).attr("href").valueOf() 

                var dato = ""; 
                if ($(this).attr("id").valueOf() == "dato") {
                     dato = $(this).attr("data-valor").valueOf();   
                }

            })                                                                                            
            .done(function(data) {    
                if (data) {
                   $(".marco_principal").html(data);

                   if ($(this).attr("id").valueOf() == "dato") {                        
                        $(".dato").html(dato);
                    } 

                else {
                    alert("Data no tiene valor");
                }           
            })
            .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                if(jqXHR.status === 0) {
                alert('Not connect: Verify Network.');

              } else if(jqXHR.status == 404) {

                alert('Requested page not found [404]');

              } else if(jqXHR.status == 500) {

                alert('Internal Server Error [500].');          

              } else if(textStatus === 'parsererror') {

                alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');

              } else if(textStatus === 'timeout') {

                alert('Time out error.');

              } else if(textStatus === 'abort') {

                alert('Ajax request aborted.');

              } else {

                alert('Uncaught Error: ' + jqXHR.responseText);         
              }
          })
          .always(function(result) {
          });
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Podrias descomponer la url con una funcion para asi ver el o los parametros que necesites en tu validacion, algo asi:

```js
$("a").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
 //Se preparan l as variables con la data a procesar 
 var dato = $(this).attr('data-valor');
 var enlace = $(this).attr('href').valueOf();
 var id = $.get("id",enlace);
 var key = $.get("key",enlace);
 
 //Se indica la salida de la data
 $("#enlace").html("<b>El enlace es:</b> "+enlace);
 $("#dato").html("<b>El data-valor es:</b> "+dato);
 $("#valor").html("<b>La ID de URL es:</b> "+id);
 $("#key").html("<b>La KEY de URL es:</b> "+key);
})


//Esta funcion parsea la url para obtener el valor de la clave solicitada
$.get = function(key,url)   {  
        key = key.replace(/[\[]/, '\\[');  
        key = key.replace(/[\]]/, '\\]');  
        var pattern = "[\\?&]" + key + "=([^&#]*)";  
        var regex = new RegExp(pattern);  
        var urls = url;  
        var results = regex.exec(urls);  
        if (results === null) {  
            return null;  
        } else {  
            return results[1];  
        }  
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="planilla.php?id=ID_MUESTRA&key=valuenuevo" data-valor="datos">Planilla 1</a>
<a href="planilla.php?id=ID_DOCUMENTO&key=otrovalue" data-valor="datosB">Planilla 1</a>
<a href="planilla.php?id=ID_LOQUESEA&key=nuevovalue" data-valor="datosC">Planilla 1</a>
<br>
<hr>
<p id="enlace">

</p>
<p id="dato">
  
</p>
<p id="valor">
  
</p>
<p id="key">
  
</p>
```

Comment: Hola Carlos, Para mejorar la respuesta, por favor añade informacion y expliacion de cómo funciona. Mira [answer] para más info. Un saludo